# Websocket not working when I initialize socket after API call in Angular

Tags: angular, sockets, websocket

I am trying to use `websockets` with Angular.

Here is my code

```
ngOnInit(){
    const self = this;
    self.authService.init();
    self.socket = self.authService.getSocket();
    if(self.socket){
        self.socket.on("new-message", (data) => {
            console.log(data);
        });
    }
}
```

**This works perfectly fine** and whenever data is emitted with `new-message`, I receive it here.

But now I changed the logic and am initializing the socket only if the user is `authenticated`. Here is my new code:

```
ngOnInit(){
    const self = this;
 this.authService.isUserAuthenticatedbyType().then(function(isAuthenticated){
        if(isAuthenticated){
            self.authService.init();
            self.socket = self.authService.getSocket();
            if(self.socket){
                self.socket.on("new-message", (data) => {
                console.log(data);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Here, `isUserAuthenticatedbyType` has an API call which returns a boolean Promise based on if the user is `authenticated`.

Now, in the case of `authenticated` user, my socket is initialized correctly, still no message is received even after emitting the message. I am not sure what went wrong between these two approaches. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You should have the init after const self = this;

Comment: ngOnInit() only runs on initialisation. And if `isAuthenticated` false at the time of initialisation, then the code will not run again. You need to have a way to track `isAuthenticated` changes.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, this is actually the problem, but you missed a brace:

```
ngOnInit(){
    const self = this;
 this.authService.isUserAuthenticatedbyType().then(function(isAuthenticated){
        if(isAuthenticated){
            self.authService.init();
            self.socket = self.authService.getSocket();
            if(self.socket){
                self.socket.on("new-message", (data) => {
                console.log(data);
            });
            } // this one ends if(self.socket)
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that is not the problem. It is just a typo while typing the question here.

Comment: Did you try using Chromes built-in websocket trace? Is it opened correctly? Do the messages arrive there? If not => its senders problem. If yes, it’s something in your ja layer...

Comment: Thanks, I figured out my problem. Actually this code was in app.component.ts. So upon launching the app, the user was unauthenticated, so socket was not initialized. After login, this flow was not getting called. However, if I was refreshing the page, it used to work since user has already logged in previously and details were saved in local storage. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try to return an observable from `isUserAuthenticatedbyType()`, and then subscribe to it. Then you can track `isAuthenticated` changes.

```
ngOnInit(){
  const self = this;
  this.authService.isUserAuthenticatedbyType()
    .subscribe((isAuthenticated) => {
      if(isAuthenticated){
        self.authService.init();
        self.socket = self.authService.getSocket();
        if(self.socket){
            self.socket.on("new-message", (data) => {
            console.log(data);
        });
      } // this one ends if(self.socket)
    }
  });
}
```